# Exchange Server 2003 ActiveSync not working with iPhone

Tags: exchange, firewall, iphone, port, activesync

I am trying to get our iPhones connected via ActiveSync with Exchange Server 2003 SP2.

I have an SSL cert and OWA is working fine using HTTPS. I have 443 open on the firewall and pointed at the single Exchange server. The cert is for mail.domainname.com.  When I try to connect the iPhones it just continues to ask for a password and will eventually come back with an error that it could not get mail.

I have IMAP working fine on the iPhone but would like to shut down the service and just use ActiveSync.  I don't have an iPhone to test with so I have to continue to bother users to try new options of settings on the iPhone, which is getting to be a little embarassing.  Everthing I am reading says that once 443 this open with a cert this is a no brainer to get it connected.

I am unsure at this point if I have a configuration issue with the way I am putting in the settings on the iPhone or if there is another setting I am missing on Exchange or the firewall.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: I failed to mention we have a Sonicwall firewall and a Baracuda spam filter.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has a "tool" (in the form of a web site and robotic ActiveSync client) that might help you out: https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/  This will help you, especially, since you don't have your own ActiveSync client to test with.

I have yet to have an E2K3 installation of any age "just work" out of the box with ActiveSync. Typically I find things like SSL required on the "/exchange" directory, or the "Negotiate" authentication provider not being set, etc.

Microsoft offers some general guidance at: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/330463

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I found this article and I am making some progress.  http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=817379
Instead of getting a system error when trying to connect to OMA via IE,  I am now getting to my mailbox.  Not quite sure why I needed to deny access for my exchange server to the new virtual directory I created for OMA or why I couldn't use the default OMA virtual directory, but it seems to be working.  Will test on an iPhone when I can get my hands on one.   Thank you.

Comment: +1 that online tool provided by Microsoft is very helpful. I once discovered that authorization on the IIS web had too many unnecessary options activated.