# What are known MS Exchange / iPhone ActiveSync limitations?

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange, exchange-2003, iphone, calendar

I am currently using Microsoft Exchange 2003 on Windows Server 2003 with various iPhone 3G, 3GS, and 4s.  The iPhones have all been upgraded to the latest firmware.  Users are using Outlook 2007.

An example I am finding is that normal calendar events added from either Outlook or iPhone sync fine but if I am the "meeting organizer" sending a "meeting request" the event will show in my Outlook but not on my iPhone.

Is there any good list of Exchange/iPhone ActiveSync limitations?  Any workaround for the issue above?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm a little curious about how you have this working at all. I thought that Exchange 2007 onwards is a requirement to get activesync working between exchange and an iPhone.

Comment: Unless I am confusing the terminology of ActiveSync, an iPhone has been able to sync mail, contacts, and calendars OTA with Exchange 2003 since at least iOS 3.0, maybe even at 2.0.

Comment: @Robert:  We're currently using Exchange 2003 and iPhone 3GS with iOS4 and it works flawlessly.

Comment: I guess so. You learn something new every day.

Comment: Have you tried the tool mentioned here?  http://serverfault.com/questions/67192/exchange-server-2003-activesync-not-working-with-iphone